# How to call Java File from MYSQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

I have two tables allocation_request and allocation_request_audit_logs. I used trigger on allocation_request table, If any data insert/update on allocation_request table, trigger will call and data will insert into allocation_request_audit_logs. But problem is, whenever allocation_request_audit_logs will update then I need to call Scheduler job.
How to call Java class/code from MYSQL Stored Procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to call Java code directly from a MySQL stored procedure through a `UDF` or `User Defined Function`.

Take a look at this other answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9777662/236528

And more details here on how to make it work:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/39547/3257